# How to present some combination of text, images, equations in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am developing a web app to teach Electrical Engineering laboratories (maybe something similar to Code Academy, for example). The app will guide the student through theory, simulations, and then hardware experiments. I'm trying to figure out a way to best present the theory to the students, while making the Admin part as simple as possible.

My current solution is to have a Theory model and a series of TheoryElement models associated with it. The TheoryElement can be either text, an image or an equation.

**MODELS:**

```
class Theory(models.Model):
    lab = models.ForeignKey(Laboratory)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class TheoryElement(models.Model):
    theory = models.ForeignKey(Theory)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    text_input = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image_input = models.FileField(upload_to='VLA/static/VLA/images/', blank=True)
    equation_input = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    is_text = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_equation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_latex = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**VIEW:**

```
{% if theory_elements %}
{% for element in theory_elements %}
    {% if element.is_text %}
        <p>{{ element.text_input}}</p>
    {% elif element.is_image %}
        <p><center><img src="{% static element.image_input %}"></center></p>
    {% elif element.is_equation %}
        {% if element.is_latex %}
            <p><center>$${{ element.equation_input}}$$</center></p>
        {% else %}
            <p><center>{{ element.equation_input}}</center></p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Essentially, the instructor would just add a TheoryElement for each paragraph of text, image, or equation, and select the relevant Boolean (is_text, is_image, is_equation). The View then prints out each TheoryElement sequentially, in the order they were added.

My question:

1. Is there a better way of doing this?
2. If not, is there a way to force the user to set only one of 'is_text', 'is_equation', 'is_image' as True? As I have written it one could choose any combination

I would also like to allow the possibility of a Table. So each TheoryElement would be one of text, image, equation, or table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a single field with CHOICES?

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
  ('equation', 'equation'),
  ('text', 'text'),
  ('image', 'image'),
  ('table', 'table')
)

type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty new to Django, so this didn't occur to me. Still seems like there could be a slicker way of doing all of this.